# Getting "Code has been terminated" error on Dialog.Show

Tags: excel, vba

```
    sub button1_click
    Dim a as FileDialog
    set a=Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    a.show
    end sub
```

Getting the error message window pointing to line `a.show`, when i click on `button1`. Even if i use `application.displayalerts=false`, I still get that error.

Please help

Comment: msoFileDialogPicker doesn't exists. msoFileDialogFilePicker or msoFileDialogFolderPicker.

Comment: it was just a typing error, indeed i have used msoFileDialogFolderPicker in my code

Comment: The code works fine for me in Excel 2013.  Can you check to see if you're missing any references (in the VBA IDE..Tools => References)?

Comment: hey atlast seems i found the issue. i was working on a remote machine, and dont know the reason for this problem, but i changed the remote machine and everything seems to be good. Thanks although..

Answer (score 0):

hey at last seems i found the issue. i was working on a remote machine, and dont know the reason for this problem, but i changed the remote machine and everything seems to be good. Thanks although.. to all –  No more attention on this is needed.